Derivative of $ f(x)=\int_{1 / x}^{e^x / x} \frac{\cos (x t)}{t} d t $
Find the derivative of the function
$$
f(x)=\int_{1 / x}^{e^x / x} \frac{\cos (x t)}{t} d t, \quad(x>0) .
$$
I use $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{1 / x}^{e^x / x} \frac{\cos (x t)}{t} d t=\frac{x\cos(e^x)}{e^x}\frac{(x-1)e^x}{x^2}-x\cos(1)(-\frac{1}{x^2})=\cos(e^x)-\frac{\cos(e^x)}{x}+\frac{\cos(1)}{x}$
The answer is supposed to be $f^\prime(x)=\cos(e^x)$, unsure if I have messed up somewhere or why the last part takes out each other.

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus

Since $f(x)$ is given as the integral of a function, the best approach seems to use the Lebinitz's rule. But the function inside the integral also has $x$ which poses a problem. so first lets just try to eliminate $x$ from inside the integral:
put $$xt=z\implies x\cdot dt=dz\\
\implies f(x)=\int_1^{e^x}\frac{\cos z}z\cdot dz\\$$
Now just apply Lebinitz's Rule:
$$\implies f'(x)=\frac{\cos(e^x)}{e^x}\cdot e^x=\cos(e^x)$$
LEBINITZ'S RULE
If$$ H(x)=\int_{g(x)}^{f(x)} h(t)\cdot dt\\
\implies H'(x)=h(f(x))\cdot f'(x)-h(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$
